# filling with zeros the list obtained from a comparison

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have a function that receives 3 lists:

doc1:

```
[['ser', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['francisco_villa', 'NP00000', 2], ['norte', 'NCMS000', 1], ['revolucion_mexicana', 'NP00000', 1], ['nombrar', 'VMP00SM', 1], ['centauro', 'NCMS000', 1]]
```

doc2:

```
[['pintor', 'NCMS000', 1], ['ser', 'VSIS3S0', 1], ['muralista', 'AQ0CS0', 1], ['diego_rivera', 'NP00000', 1], ['frida_kahlo', 'NP00000', 1], ['caso', 'NCMS000', 1]]
```

consulta:

```
[['ser', 'VSIP3S0', 1], ['francisco_villa', 'NP00000', 1], ['quien', 'NP00000', 1]]
```

function:

```
def vectores(doc1,doc2,consulta):
res=[]
l1=[]
cont = 0
r = doc1 + doc2 + consulta
for i in r:
    l1.append(i[0])
for e in doc1:
    if e[0] in l1:
        res.append(e[2])
    else:
        res.append(e[0]==0 * len(l1))
return res

[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1] -> res
```

I need to compare if the key[0] of doc1 exists in key[0] of l1, if so append key[2] to the res list, **and if they don't match append zeros to the res list building a vector with lenght l1**

I'd like to get an output like this:`[1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, ...]`

-The elements of the output vector are the key[2] value of the lists.
-The zeros would be that the words of doc1 are not in l1.
- Once I have the desire output I´d like also to repeat the same procedure with doc2 and consulta.

Thank you in advance! ;)

Comment: You might want to reformulate, I don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: So you are having trouble getting the `res.append(e[0]==0 * len(l1))` part to put a 0 in the list?  And you havent tried res.append(0)?

Comment: Yeah I tried res.append(0) and it doesn't work cuz, len(doc1) is smaller than len(l1). I need len(res) to be equal to len(l1) w/ zeros in the absence of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the explanation you gave me in the comments, here is my attempt:

```py
def vectores(doc1, doc2, consulta):

    thingies = doc1 + doc2 + consulta
    result = [0] * len(thingies)
    for index,value in enumerate([ item[2] for item in doc1 ]):
        result[index] = value

    return result
```

```
print result
>>> [ 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ]
      <-------------->  <-------------->  <----->
            doc1              doc2        consulta
```

You are comparing `doc1` with `doc1+doc2+consulta`. I still don't get how `result` could be useful, but this is what you asked.

Answer (score 0):

Well I think that this should do it cuz the order doesn't matter:

```
def vectores(doc1,doc2,consulta):
res=[]
l1=[]
cont = 0
r = doc1 + doc2 + consulta
for i in r:
    l1.append(i[0])
    res.append(0) #  create the list w/ zeros
for e in doc1:
    if e[0] in l1:
        res.append(e[2])
    else:
        if e[0] not in l1:
            res.append(0) # I don´t know if this is redundant

return res

res = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

Comment: Feel free to comment if you can simplify this. Thanks ;)

Comment: You result is not what you're looking for. Your result contains as many `0` as `len(l1)` plus the `key[2]` of `doc1`. What do you want in the end ?

Comment: This is what I think: you do want to build a list as long as `len(doc1+doc2+consulta)` containing either `0` or `doc1[i][2]`. What is the point ? You could just have done `res = [0]*len(l1)`

Comment: Well, I still didn't get what you want to do (even though I am prettty sure it is not hard to implement). Please update your post so I can see on one hand the content of your initial datas (`doc1`, `doc2` and `consulta`) and on the other hand the actual result you want to get for those particular initial datas. That way I'll understand correctly what you want to achieve.

Comment: I want to compare 1st element of doc1 w/ 1st element with r =doc1+doc2+consulta, if it is there put the 3rd element in res list if not put a zero.